# How can I force a certain page to revalidate from a client component in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

### The problem

I'm making a website with a supabase backend, where people can make things called guides. Each guide has a dedicated dynamic path `/guides/[id]` and a dedicated edit page `/guides/[id]/edit`, which contains the form for updating the data in the guide. On submitting the form, I use `router.push()` from `next/navigation` to navigate back to `/guides/[id]` after making the requests to supabase. However, when it navigates back to `/guides/[id]`, it still shows the old cached data - I need to refresh the page to get the updated data.

I don't want to revalidate the page every time it's visited, I only want to revalidate it whenever the form is submitted. Is there a way to do that?

### Attempted solutions

I looked at the NextJS docs for `revalidatePath`. I tried using the function directly in my solution like this:

```ts
...
revalidatePath(`/guides/${id}`);
router.push(`/guides/${id}`);
...
```

But ended up with this error:

```
Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag _N_T_/guides/18
```

leading me to believe it could only be called server-side. So, I tried creating an api route `/api/revalidate/route.ts` like so:

```ts
// /api/revalidate/route.ts
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const path = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("path");

  if (path) {
    revalidatePath(path);
    return Response.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() });
  }

  return Response.json({
    revalidated: false,
    now: Date.now(),
    message: "Missing path to revalidate",
  });
}
```

```ts
// /guide/[id]/edit.tsx
...
await fetch(`/api/revalidate?path=/guides/${id}`);
router.push(`/guides/${id}`);
...
```

But that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right `revalidatePath` function can only be called server-side [Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating).
So let's explore some options:

One possible reason for the error is that `revalidatePath` function is not triggering a re-validation as we expect.
The re-validation will happen on the next request to the page after the mark is set [Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating).

Another possible reason could be that the `revalidatePath` function is not able to find the path in the cache. i would ask you to check if the path you're passing to `revalidatePath` matches the correct path [Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath).

Lastly try using `router.refresh` method to force a refresh of the page after the form submission.[Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching), [Source](https://medium.com/@devdo/how-to-force-a-page-refresh-in-next-js-6326cae49fe4).

i wrote an example:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const MyComponent = () => {
 const router = useRouter();

 const handleFormSubmit = async () => {
   // Perform your form submission logic here...

   // After the form submission, refresh the page
   router.refresh();
 };

 return (
   <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
     {/* Your form fields here... */}
   </form>
 );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

`handleFormSubmit` is the function that gets called when the form is submitted and then it refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you! Forcing the router to refresh before navigating back did the trick.

Comment: i'm glad it worked!! i must point out that `router.refresh` will slow the user in navigating your webpage

Comment: True, but considering I'm only doing this when a form is being submitted, I'm willing to allow that occasional slowdown

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue , but found a much simpler solution , we can use [search Params](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#searchparams-optional) as it marks the route as [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-functions).

After this setup i would do

```
  router.push("/your/route?new=1");
```

This would make sure that your page renders dynamically when the request is made.

Comment: Nice trick! I'll try using that in case I run into the problem again.

Comment: Apparently you can also do router.push("/your/route?") and it still works. At least it did for me.